# how do i get the contents from " value="" "

Tags: bash, curl

This is the code :

```
#!/bin/bash
head=`curl -D -s "http://example.com/" | grep "j_id__v_0:javax.faces.ViewState:2"`
echo $head
```

and the output in terminal :

```
            </script>
            <input type="hidden" name="GlobalFooter_SUBMIT" value="1" />
            <input type="hidden" name="javax.faces.ViewState" id="j_id__v_0:javax.faces.ViewState:2" value="V7wZDq4cDizFPZ0i52hQGUD25XgWp5NJC+hCql33eTTwC2hm" autocomplete="off" />
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

How do I print the contents of the value?

Comment: You can use an HTML parser.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454 , but maybe also just `... | grep -o 'value="\K[^"+)"'` , or if your `grep` doesn't understand that, `perl -lne 'print $1 if /value="([^"]+)"/'`

Comment: Print to file? Just `cat` it with `>`.

Answer (score 0):

Add a `sed` after the `grep` to keep only the value:

```
#!/bin/bash

head=$(curl -D -s "http://example.com/" | grep "j_id__v_0:javax.faces.ViewState:2" | sed 's/.*\svalue="\(\S*\)"\s.*/\1/')
echo $head
```

Couple points:

- use the `$()` syntax to assign commands results to a variable.  The backtick syntax, altough it works, is legacy syntax.
- `\s`: whitespace
- `\S`: anything but whitespace.  I used that since `.*` is greedy and would include everything after `value="SOMETHING" autocomplete="off`